# Get all element of same class and detect first element from that via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors, jquery-filter

I've dynamic structure where data is coming in below way. I want to filter all element with class name "My_data" and take first of it. in below code structure i want to get first "My_data" class element.

```
<div class="all_data">
<div class="listing">
    <div class="other_1">Block One</div>
    <div class="mbox">Block Two</div>
    <div class="other_2">Block Three</div>
    <div class="mbox">Block Four</div>
</div>
<div class="listing">
    <div class="other_1">Block One</div>
    <div class="mbox">Block Two</div>
    <div class="other_2">Block Three</div>
    <div class="mbox">Block Four</div>
</div>
<div class="listing">
    <div class="other_2">Block One</div>
    <div class="My_data">My data 1</div>
    <div class="other_2">Block Three</div>
    <div class="My_data">My data 2</div>
</div>
<div class="listing">
    <div class="other_5">Block One</div>
    <div class="My_data">My data 3</div>
    <div class="other_2">Block Three</div>
    <div class="My_data">My data 4</div>
</div>
</div>
```

so from above code structure I want to select **My data 1**

Please note: this data structure is dynamic so it might be change every time. sometimes first listing div get "My_data" class and some time no listing div has it.

Comment: Thanks @JeffreyWesterkamp for your response. But as I said no inner data will be static, it will be dynamic. Only thing which is not going to change is class name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var myDataDiv = document.querySelector('.My_data')
var myData = myDataDiff && myDataDiff.innerText; // > string | null
```

---

[`document.querySelector('.My_data')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) will either return *the first* element with class `My_data` - if it exists - or null otherwise. Therefore `myData` will either be `null` or the result of `myDataDiff.innerText`.

Comment: Thanks @JeffreyWesterkamp for your response. But as I said no inner data will be static, it will be dynamic. Only thing which is not going to change is class name. so we can not get it via innerText.

Comment: I don't understand. In what way will it be dynamic that prevents you from finding the first element with (static) class `My_data`? Is there more HTML inside?

Comment: In simple way 
- There will be many element in body with class name "My_data"
- But I want to find first element in body with class name "My_data".

Comment: That is [what querySelector does](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).

Answer (score 1):

Just make one empty div and append all child divs of listing class in it. After that take the first from that new list.